# Вывод значения регистра в консоль

Tags: windows, ассемблер, fasm

Знаю, что надо гуглить и всё такое, но не мог бы кто-то выложить полный код вывода значения регистра на экран консоли? Пробовал с прерыванием `int 21h`, но были ошибки в программе.

Comment: Гуглите sprintf и WriteConsole. Если нужно, позже набросаю пример.

P.S. printf из msvcrt.dll тоже вариант. Досовские прерывания под windows не работают.

Comment: P.S. printf использует соглашение вызова cdecl, поэтому после его вызова нужно выравнивать стек на размер переданных ему аргументов:

    push eax
    push hello
    call [printf]
    sub esp, 8

В данном примере выравнивание не играет особой роли, но если вызов printf будет внутри функции, то при выходе из функции на вершине стека может оказаться все что угодно, а не адреса возврата.

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code executable
start:
        mov eax, 555
        push eax
        push hello
        call [printf]
        sub esp, 8  ; Выравнивание стека после вызова cdecl функции
        push 0
        call [ExitProcess]

section '.rdata' data readable
        hello db 'Hello %d', 10, 0

section '.idata' data readable import
        library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll', \
                msvcrt,   'msvcrt.dll'
        import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
        import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'
```